# Twitter bootstrap - left and right margin in IE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using latest bootstrap from twitter.
I am on a early stage for designing my site.

the issue is, when I view site on other browsers except IE 7-8 it looks ok but on IE 7-8 includes extra margin on both left and right side of the body, thus all the contents goes weird and overlap each other.

I don't have a clue why its happening

please assist

Regards

Comment: If you want some help, post some code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way!

In IE I make the span move by adding padding and margin...not sure if it's the right way but it works (span 7 is my left column and span5 is my right one)!

```
<!--[if gte IE 5]>
```

.span7 {
     margin-left:-150px
}
.span5 {
    padding-left:150px
}

```
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be IE7 and IE8's lack of support for media queries that is causing this layout issue.

If you are looking at the page on a large monitor say, and it falls under the media query @media (min-width: 1200px), IE7/8 may not pick up any width/margin/padding CSS values that are assigned by that media query.

A good way to see if this is the issue is to download Scott Jehl's respond.js [here on GitHub](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) into your js directory. It used to be included in Modernizr but I think it is an optional addition now. Basically it gives IE7/8 knowledge about media queries.

I call it from the head of the page, inside the existing conditional comments that load the HTML5shim for IE.

```
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
```

Once it is loaded, you will see what layout difference it makes.

Hope this helps.